# Web.py db.insert() does not insert the row

Tags: python, mysql, web.py

I am using Web.py 0.37, and trying to add a row to my mysql database. Here is my code:

```
com.globals.db.insert('users', email=data.email, fullname=data.fullname, password=pwh, _test=False)
```

And this is the output (in the debugger window):

```
0.09 (2): INSERT INTO users (fullname, password, email) VALUES ('Juan', 'f3bab99...d05cee4', 'no@email.com')
0.09 (3): SELECT last_insert_id();
30
```

I can see the id field incrementing, but when I check the database, there is no new rows created. Why is this happening? The outputted sql statement executes fine in the mysql terminal.

Comment: Did you commit the data? Most likely you are using transactions and will need to commit the data to see it in other processes. I don't know how to do this in Web.py though!

Comment: This is the probable answer. I'd upvote an answer to this effect.

Comment: Dude. You are my savior. I, for some reason, enabled transactions at the start of my code. Removing that fixed my problem.

Comment: @NickCraig-Wood: Your comment helped the OP, you should make it the answer do it can be accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you commit the data?

Most likely you are using transactions and will need to commit the data to see it in other processes.

I don't know how to do this in Web.py though!

(Copied from my original comment at Helgi's suggestion)